# Trying to load a package in Julia

Tags: module, package, julia

I'd like to use the function `bitrand()`, which is in the `compat.jl` package. Here is what I did:

```
julia> Pkg.add("compat")
INFO: Nothing to be done

julia> using Compat

julia> bitrand()
ERROR: bitrand not defined

julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Updating METADATA...
INFO: Computing changes...
INFO: No packages to install, update or remove

julia> using Compat

julia> bitrand()
ERROR: bitrand not defined

julia> Compat.bitrand()
ERROR: bitrand not defined
```

For info, I am using `Julia-0.3.2`. Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
julia> Pkg.status()
3 required packages:
 - Compat                        0.2.10
 - Distributions                 0.6.3
 - StatsBase                     0.6.10
3 additional packages:
 - ArrayViews                    0.4.8
 - JSON                          0.4.0
 - PDMats                        0.3.1

julia> Pkg.add("Compat")
INFO: Nothing to be done

julia> using Compat

julia> bitrand()
ERROR: bitrand not defined
```

Comment: Does capitalisation matter for package names? I think it does, i.e. try `Pkg.add("Compat")` not `Pkg.add("compat")`

Comment: What does `Pkg.status()` show?

Comment: See edits in response to the two comments.

Comment: I'm not sure then. I can confirm I'm getting the same behaviour on my machine (v0.3.5).

Comment: I too have no `bitrand()` following `using Compat`.  Note that according to [#9569](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9569), `bitrand` has only very recently replaced `randbool()`.  Perhaps this change has not yet propagated to our installed code.

Comment: Indeed `randbool()` seems to produce exactly what I expected from `bitrand()`. You can probably make an answer out of your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This definitely works for me on Julia v0.3.3 with Compat.jl v0.2.10, so can you do the following:

1. `Pkg.rm("Compat")`
2. Run `readdir(Pkg.dir())` to confirm its gone
3. `Pkg.update()`
4. `Pkg.add("Compat")` with a capital C
5. Close and re-open Julia, just to be sure
6. `using Compat`

Comment: Very nice.  `bitrand()` had been missing and is now available following this procedure.  (My Julian version is   `0.3.5` as provided by some Ubuntu packages.)

Comment: Whoah how complicated! It works indeed. Thanks a lot!  The other solution was, as @MikeSatteson said to use `randbool()` instead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just wanted to 100% make sure it worked :D Glad to hear.